# Bitrix24 Application Embedding

Tags: bitrix

I am working on an application for my Bitrix system. I'm trying to embed into the tasks module, but I'm having some trouble getting the embedding to actually work. Below is my javascript code that should be handling the embedding.

```
BX24.rest.callMethod(
    'placement.bind',
    params: {
        PLACEMENT: 'TASK_VIEW_TAB',
        HANDLER: '*URL FOR CODE WITHIN BITRIX SERVER*',
        TITLE: 'Test Tab',
        DESCRIPTION: 'Test Tab',
    }
);
```

Have I done something incorrectly in my code? This is the code that is set up to run when the application is installed. If this is all I need, perhaps I'm missing a step that actually installs the application (it's a private application currently).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax should be as follows:

```
BX24.callMethod(
    'placement.bind',
    {
        PLACEMENT: 'TASK_VIEW_TAB',
        HANDLER: '*URL FOR CODE WITHIN BITRIX SERVER*',
        TITLE: 'Test Tab',
        DESCRIPTION: 'Test Tab',
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set Access permissions for "Application embedding (placement)" in order to use placement methods.